# How to enter numbers and format in real time into "mm:ss.S"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm writing a timing/pacing app for runners.  A key feature of the app is being able to enter in a goal time.

I know I'll be able to accomplish my goal using an `editText` for each minutes, seconds, and milliseconds section, but that would be a pain for me and the user.  The idea I have in my head is like entering an alarm time, like in the timely app (I tried to post an image but I don't have enough reputation).  The string would begin as "--:--.-" and get filled from the right as numbers are entered.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it another go I guess

Comment: If you have tried something and cannot get it to work - please post the code and we will try to help. Otherwise, you should ask elsewhere as StackOverflow is not a place for seeking free source code.

Comment: In future please refer to this [excellent guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that can explain how to format a question so that it will _improve_ your chances of getting an answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format()` to fill it for example, if your data is an Integer:

```
String time;
    if(!(minute==0 && second==0 && miliSecond==0))
        time = String.format("%02d:%02d.&1d",mminute,second,miliSecond);
    else 
      time="--:--.-";
```